# Realtime Database returning deleted values [EDITED]

Tags: database, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

I deleted everything in my database. Then, I queried the data that was just deleted and I get results! How is this possible?

I am using the Realtime Database Unity SDK. For testing purposes, I want to regularly purge the whole database and populate it with new data. Imagine my surprise when my queries returned some old, deleted data. It is as if the deleted data persists in some void that can still be accessed.

I have been tinkering with this issue for days now. Here are my steps:

1. I'm using `GetReference(item).Push().Key;` which auto-generates a unique key.
2. I write the new `item` to the database with `GetReference(item).SetValueAsync()`.
3. I check my Firebase console, and indeed, the data was correctly recorded.
4. I create a query that returns the JSON value of `item`. I works fine.
5. I delete `item` from the data base.
6. I run the query again and `item` is returned. ITEM IS NOT SUPPOSED TO EXIST ANYMORE!

Out of curiosity, I write a query to return all the data in my database (which should be empty) and it returns every object I have create over the last few days. This is literally hundreds of items....from an empty database.

It seems like data persists for a few days after it is deleted.

Realizing this I decided to test what would happen if I manually made an object that uses an existing key from one of the deleted objects.

My query returns the new object. Yay!
I take a break and come back 15 minutes later. I run the exact query again. I get the old, deleted object and not the new one. WHAT THE HECK IS GOING ON?

At this point I am questioning whether Realtime Database is even a real database. It seems to break the rules of both consistency and integrity.

I've also considered that I might be deleting the data incorrectly. I was mostly doing it manually, through the browser. I also have tried `RemoveValueAsync()` and `SetRawJsonValueAsync(null)`. Nothing seems to make a difference.

Please, please, please can someone tell me what is going on? I will be forever grateful.

---

EDIT: It turns out that the phantom data was coming from the cache on my device. Turning persistence off solved the problem. Apparently, performing the same query multiple times only retrieves the data for the database the first time. The subsequent queries look into the cache.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the phantom data was coming from the cache on my device. Turning persistence off solved the problem. Apparently, performing the same query multiple times only retrieves the data for the database the first time. The subsequent queries look into the cache.

Comment: would love to see what code does this as its not listed on the documentation for Unity